# Unable to move my perks class to the right

Tags: html, css

I tried commenting out all of my css except the perks class and I still couldn't get it to move to the right by changing the margin.

I'm relatively new to CSS so I might be making an obvious mistake but I've spent a few hours trying to debug and since it's not the margins of the rest of my css, or any of my other classes interfering with perks.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s4cu7c3c/)

```css
body {
  background: url("costume.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  font-family: athelas;
}
.intro {
  margin: 0, 0, 20px, 0;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 25%
}
ul {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  font-size: 20px;
}
li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0px 15px 0px 0px;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  text-align: center;
}
p {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  text-align: center;
}
form {
  right: 251px;
}
input {
  padding: 8px;
  right: 25px;
}
input[type="text"] {
  border: none;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
input[type="password"] {
  margin: 15px 0px 0px 20px;
  border: none;
}
button {
  width: 120px;
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: rgba(133, 68, 176, 0.75);
  font-family: athelas;
  font-size: 16px;
  right: 25px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 80%;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}
.friends {
  background: url(jessa.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 30% 0 0 43%;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.hahaid {
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 63px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 28px;
}
.hahaid:hover {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 70px 50px 73px 50px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  opacity: 1;
}
.perks {
  background: url(roadtrip.jpg);
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Profile</li>
    <li>Chat</li>
    <li>Login</li>
    <li>Sign up</li>
  </ul>

  <div class="intro">
    <h1>What are you waiting for?</h1>
    <p>You can use this messaging client to send actual messages to other humans!</p>
    <p>This is legit guys, I swear.</p>
    <form action="profile_form.asp">
      <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
      <br>
      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
      <br>
      <button type="submit" value="Login" style="border:none;">Submit</button>
    </form>

  </div>
  <div class="friends">
    <p class="hahaid">Chat with friends.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="perks">
    <p class="coolbeans">Connect with family.</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Paste both codes in jsfiddle.net to reproduce the issue

Comment: Please add your code here and not on pastbin. If for some reason (now or in the future) you can not go to pastbin the question will not be clear anymore.

Comment: What is your desired outcome? adding margin to the right will actually move the content more to the left (so I am confused) - do you mean to simply `float:right` the entire div?

Comment: I added a fiddle to it

Comment: When I add margin to the left it doesn't move it to the right either. I tried adding margin to the right just to test to see if it would do anything, but even when I increase the margin to the left it doesn't move and I don't understand why. I tried to float the entire div and that didn't work either.

Comment: or, okay, if I float the entire div to the right it goes *all* the way to the right, but i'm unable to use margin to make it go exactly where I want it to: somewhere in the right center.

Comment: Why is there the class *coolbeans*? It does not appear in the CSS

Comment: I was going to add a hover element to coolbeans, and no I haven't created the css for coolbeans yet, but I didn't think that would effect the position of  perks.

Comment: Hi. I'm trying to understand how you ultimately want these two divs to act. When my browser is maximized, the div is aligned to the right. When I reduce the browser size, the perks div renders beneath the friends div. I added outlines to show the divs in my screenshots. ![non breaking](http://i28.photobucket.com/albums/c205/Josh_Blauvelt/ss1_zps5dewml3q.png) and ![breaking](http://i28.photobucket.com/albums/c205/Josh_Blauvelt/ss2_zpsmlqnvwxt.png)

Comment: Stackoverflow supports snippets, no need to use jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I got it centered with this:

```
.perks {
    background: url(roadtrip.jpg); 
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 1% 10% 10% 12%;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
}
```

Not exactly a proper fix; however, I am going to assume that this will be thrown off with different screen resolutions but in the jsfiddle it looks right.

New [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s4cu7c3c/1/)